# Python Mysql and dynamically defining fields

Tags: python, mysql-python

Is it possible to dynamically define the ORDER BY field through parameters? Through a relentless search, I've come up with that you can't.

So I thought I would ask if you can? Or if there is a work around to do it?

Example:

```
sql = "SELECT `xyz` FROM `checkins` WHERE `name`=%s AND `timestamp` >=%s AND `timestamp` < %s ORDER BY `xyz` DESC LIMIT 1"

query.execute(sql, (name, start, end))
```

works

```
sql = "SELECT `xyz` FROM `checkins` WHERE `name`=%s AND `timestamp` >=%s AND `timestamp` < %s ORDER BY `%s` DESC LIMIT 1"

query.execute(sql, (name, start, end, field))
```

does not work

The aim is to make the ORDER BY field dynamically defined (with the field variable), however when I do try to define dynamically, it keeps coming back with unknown field or disregarding the field because it's changing it to 'defined_field' with quotes

I have tried removing the ` from the ORDER BY as well

Comment: Yes - you'll have to give a more specific example though for us to help

Comment: @kbball done :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am biased against %s for something like this. You could try:

```
name = 'kbball'
start = '2017'
end = '2018'
field = 'field'

sql = "SELECT `xyz` FROM `checkins` WHERE `name`= " + name + " AND `timestamp` >= " + start + " AND `timestamp` < " + end + " ORDER BY `"+ field + "` DESC LIMIT 1"

print(sql)

#output SELECT `xyz` FROM `checkins` WHERE `name`= kbball AND `timestamp` >= 2017 AND `timestamp` < 2018 ORDER BY `field` DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Fair enough :-) I just thought it was best practice to use %s for queries